# Could you please help me to identify the location?

Tags: italy, spain, where-on-earth, beaches

Can anyone identify the location shown in this painting? [image]

Comment: Do you have any additional info? I fear this may be very difficult with just the picture, which lacks any identifying features, and is probably not a very accurate rendition. Things could also have changed a lot since it was painted. How do you know it's in Spain, or that it actually depicts a real location?

Answer (score 6):

**This is probably not a real place.** It looks stylistically *very* similar to [this painting on Alibaba](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32661658770.html), which are churned out in bulk by painting "factories" like [Dafen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dafen_Village) in China by mix and matching various elements: for example, the palm trees on the left are near identical to yours.